If proofs can be checked by computers, will we ever mistakenly believe a false proof?
As I understand, math proofs can be formalized and checked by a computer. Does this mean the math community will never have to deal with believing incorrect proofs?
If not, is the issue with adoption in that the formalization process is too difficult? Or perhaps that the formalization can introduce bugs just as math proofs can (on rare occasions) have mistaken logic?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Most advanced math proof are currently not written in such a way that they can be checked by a computer.

Welcome to Math SE. FYI, I believe questions like this one, as you appear to be basically asking about using proof assistants, may be better suited for the Proof Assistants SE site (although as currently written it's likely too opinion based to be able to be properly answered on any site, so please consider making it more specific). Also, before possibly posting anything there, please at least first check for any duplicates, read their Help Center re: what's appropriate and what's not, etc.
